# Displaying Average Integer in Array using Driver Program

Tags: java, arrays

I need practice with my syntax. I have an array of numbers and with that are methods to find the average, report highest number, and report the lowest number. To report the highest/lowest numbers I will be sorting the array.
But first my problem is with reporting the average. I think that if I can understand that part, then the min/max will be no problem. I have tried changing it to say Driver.randomArray[].getAverage() as well.

Are there any suggestions? Thanks in advance.
~Crystal

error code:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>     randomArray cannot be resolved to a type
>   Class cannot be resolved to a type
>     Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete Expression
>
> at IntegerArray.main(IntegerArray.java:48)

and it refers to my attempt to call the average from this line,

> System.out.println(randomArray[].getAverage());

First, Driver Class

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Driver {


    private static final int MAX = 0;

    public Driver(){
        int[] randomArray = new int [MAX];
        int sum;
        final int MAX; 
    }

    public int getAverage(){
        for (int index = 0; index < MAX; index++){
            int sum = 0;
            int[] randomArray = null;
            int average;
            sum = sum + randomArray[index];
            average = sum/MAX;
            return average;}

        }

    public void sortArray(){
        // sort the array from smallest to biggest
          int[] randomArray;
        Arrays.sort(randomArray);

          System.out.println("The sorted array from smallest to biggest is:");
          for (int number : randomArray) {
          System.out.println( + number)}
    }
    public int getMin(){
                int[] randomArray;
              // find the lowest number
                return randomArray[0];

          }
    public int getMax(){
                int[] randomArray;
                // find the highest number
               return randomArray[MAX];

          }


    }
```

Then my main class:

---

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.util.Arrays;


    public class IntegerArray {



    public static void main (String[] args) {
            // set up the constant for the size of the array
            final int MAX = 10;
            int sum = 0;
            int average = 0;

            int[] randomArray = new int [MAX];

            for (int index = 0; index < MAX; index++)

                // values of the array go from 0-10
                randomArray[index] = (int) (Math.random() *10);

            // prints the array
            for (int value : randomArray)
                System.out.println (value);


    System.out.println("The length of the array is: " + randomArray.length);


    System.out.println(randomArray[].getAverage());









        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The way you're creating your methods eg. getAverage() you can't call it on the array you created. On the other hand you can call them on the a Driver object you create. for example: `Driver driver = new Driver(); System.out.println(driver.getAverage());` If you want to call them on the Array Object you should add them on the Array class (but that is something more advanced Java than this).
2. In Java Code you need to add a ; after a statement don't forget them ;). Your IDE should warn you about them.
3. When you create your getMax() method you should add the array as a parameter. So that the method knows for what Array object it should get the highest number. For example:

   public int getMax(int[] randomArray) {
         // find the highest number
         return randomArray[MAX];
   }

This counts for all your methods.

I hope this solves some of your answers if not please add a comment or something.

So here is your code after that:

Driver class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Driver {


    private static final int MAX = 0;

    public Driver() {
        int[] randomArray = new int[MAX];
        int sum;
        final int MAX;
    }

    public int getAverage() {
        int average = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < MAX; index++) {
            int sum = 0;
            int[] randomArray = null;
            sum = sum + randomArray[index];
            average = sum / MAX;
        }
        return average;
    }

    public void sortArray(int[] randomArray) {
        // sort the array from smallest to biggest
        Arrays.sort(randomArray);

        System.out.println("The sorted array from smallest to biggest is:");
        for (int number : randomArray) {
            System.out.println(+number);
        }
    }

    public int getMin(int[] randomArray) {
        // find the lowest number
        return randomArray[0];

    }

    public int getMax(int[] randomArray) {
        // find the highest number
        return randomArray[MAX];

    }
}
```

IntegerArray class:

```
public class IntegerArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // set up the constant for the size of the array
        final int MAX = 10;
        int sum = 0;
        int average = 0;

        int[] randomArray = new int[MAX];

        for (int index = 0; index < MAX; index++)

            // values of the array go from 0-10
            randomArray[index] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

        // prints the array
        for (int value : randomArray)
            System.out.println(value);


        System.out.println("The length of the array is: " + randomArray.length);

        Driver driver = new Driver();
        System.out.println(driver.getAverage());
    }
}
```

---

Reply to the question in the comments:

You should give the randomArray as the parameter with your getAverage method so that method knows on which array it should operate, example: `driver.getAverage(randomArray);`

Your getAverage method also has some flaws:
1. Your sum variable should be outside the loop because else you would set your sum to 0 every time you iterate inside the loop.
2. `int[] randomArray = null;` You shouldn't really do this line at all, this line will create a NEW int array and set its value to null while you should you use the int array you give as a parameter.

So your getAverage method becomes:

```
public int getAverage(int[] randomArray) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < randomArray.length; index++) {
            sum = sum + randomArray[index];
        }
        int average = sum / randomArray.length;
        return average;
    }
```

Comment: I do get a result now for the average, but it is 0. When I tried to change

 public int getAverage() {
        int average = 0;

to int average = null; or int average;

it wouldn't let me run the code unless it is zero. So I'm thinking that the return value is just returning that, and not what is in the loop. What do you suggest?

Comment: @zerocrys I have updated my answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you, I think I might possibly be able to figure out the MAX/MIN parts now. Thanks for all your help! I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your main class doesn't reference Driver at all, so your code cannot be called.

```
 System.out.println(randomArray[].getAverage());
```

On this line randomArray is still just an array of integers (`int[] randomArray = ...`).

You will need to create an instance of Driver, pass in whatever array you're wanting to use, and then do `.getAverage()` on that.

Answer (score 0):

randomArray is null and you are trying to read from a null array.
you need to define randomArray as a class member, not a local variable in all functions.
Local variables inside functions cannot be used as soon as function ends, and using the same name in other functions cannot help that.
Also:
define sum and average before loop. calculate and return average after loop.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things your main issue seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of [scope rules](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html). For example:

```
void method () {
    int someVariable;
}

void method2 () {
    someVariable = 2; // <-- Error.
}
```

In that code `someVariable` is local to `method` and is not available outside of it. You could not access it in `method2`.

I suggest you have a read not only of the above scope rules link, but of the official tutorial on [member variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) as well, which also describes scope. The information there will help you come up with a final strategy.

In your specific case your two most reasonable options are:

1. You could make `randomArray` a member field of your class (see above links).
2. You could pass `randomArray` as a parameter to your various methods (e.g. as a parameter to `getAverage`, see also the official tutorial on [passing information to a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)).

You have a few other issues, some mentioned in the other answers here, but my take is that is your primary confusion here. Read through the official tutorials (the docs.oracle.com links above), they're concise and well-written, and will fill in the blanks of some of your missing concepts. After you do that, give it another shot.

---

By the way, as for your compiler error on:

```
System.out.println(randomArray[].getAverage());
```

Unfortunately `randomArray[].getAverage()` simply does not make enough sense to justify a full explanation of how the compiler is interpreting it, so suffice it to say: No, that's wrong. :)

You'll want to check out that "passing information to a method" tutorial mentioned above, because it looks like you're trying to express something like this (option 2 above):

```
int getAverage (int randomArray[]) {
    ...
}

System.out.println(getAverage(randomArray));
```

As an aside: Note that the average of a bunch of integers isn't necessarily an integer itself (the average of 1 and 2 is 1.5). You might consider computing and returning a `float` or a `double` instead.